# Jena DatatypeProperty and literal

Tags: java, jena

I need to create a DatatypeProperty with domain the class created from me and for range literal that I get from user. How I can do this?

```
DatatypeProperty HasPhysicalData =m.createDatatypeProperty(SNS+"physicalObjectHasPhysicalProperty");

DatatypeProperty HasType = m.getDatatypeProperty(SNS+"physicalPropertyHasType");

HasType.addSubProperty(HasPhysicalData);

HasPhysicalData.addDomain(clsAttr);
```

Comment: What do you get from the user that prevents you from calling the `addRange` method?

Comment: I had to put literal in the range so if i create Literal literal =  m.createLiteral("example"); i can't write HasPhysicalData.addRange(literal); because the argument of the domain must be a resource not a literal

Answer (score 0):

- The range for a datatype property will be an [XML Schema URI](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-guide/#Datatypes1).
- Jena provides these URIs as Resources in the [XSD vocabulary](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/vocabulary/XSD.html) class.
- You will need to map the value that you get from the user to one of the above XSD Resources.